# Syntax Highlights of Modules in Spyder 2 Editor

Tags: python, syntax, highlight, spyder

this might be a stupid and quite unnecessary question....
I'm working with python, using the spyder 2 environment and use mostly modules like numpy, scipy, datetime, matplotlib, etc.

My question is if it is possible to somehow tell the editor to syntax-highlight said modules, e.g.

```
import numpy as np

variable = np.load('data.npy')
```

So that the "np.load" (or whatever package used from numpy) would be highlighted as a keyword or builtin like "enumerate" or "len", etc.

I am aware that this is quite unnecessary and basically a shenanigan instead of an actual problem, but I'm curious anyways.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) What you're asking for is not possible and we don't have plans to add such functionality.